# Declaring new "Class fields" dynamically inside a method - Good practice or not?

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript

This is a purely Design/Good practice issue, and I cannot provide the actual code example, but only pseudo code.

I'm working with a proprietary JavaScript framework, that gives me a concept of a Class (similarly to TypeScript) and allows me to create "Class Members/Fields" dynamically. Example using pseudo code:

```
Class Human {

    firstName;
    secondName;

    HumanConstructor() {

    }

    void method1 {
        this.title = "Mr";     // dynamically created new Class field
    }

    void method2 {
        this.addressedByName = this.title + this.firstName;
    }
}
```

Question1:  Is it a good/bad design to introduce new "class fields" inside methods?
Question2:  Is it a good/bad desgin for one method (method2) to be dependent upon the fact that other method (method1) was caleld first.

What are the advantages and drawbacks of the above two topics?

Comment: Q1: I suppose that if you introduce new fields in methods, you may break Chrome's class-based optimizations.  Chrome recommends that you define all the class fields at the very beginning of initializing the class.

Comment: Q2: Typically, you have a private field to hold the fact that method1 has (or hasn't) been called, and then check it in method2.  If method1 hasn't been called, then throw an exception.

Comment: @JonAdams this question is a poor fit for Software Engineering - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a good/bad design to introduce new "class fields" inside methods?

It is quite commonly considered bad design. There are a number of reasons. Most popular being

- the lack of immediate code understandability
- Performance issues. Since everytime you do this the js runtime (v8 etc) needs to create a new *internal* class to represent the model.

> Is it a good/bad desgin for one method (method2) to be dependent upon the fact that other method (method1) was called first.

No. That is the nature of mutable object oriented programming. The guidance is to use your intuition.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the answer I was looking for. Perhaps you could also comment on **Unit testing** comment I made earlier on Rouges answer.

Comment: Calling one function before another is a valid part of the arrange step (arrange,act,assert). Think of it similar to the fact that you need to call the constructor before you can even use method one.

Comment: What about the concern for tested method's isolation ... eg. there could be a scenario where method1 may behave unexpectedly (especially when method1 receives changes) but still pass it's own test, however it might have caused method2 test to fail (reporting a false negative result on method2). Wouldn't having a mock in place be more reliable?

Comment: It is actually not a false negative. It is method2 that did not meet its behaviour (due to any of the steps involved in arranging). It is *again* same as the constructor might work for `method1`, but might not do the right thing for say `method3`. The test for `method3` will fail but the fix needs to be in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily a drawback of it would be that if the second method is called first you'll get a NPE because title isn't initialized. In my own experience, it's better that if you know there is going to be a field used to declare it within the class, and define it within the constuctor.

Comment: Hmmm yes, your reasons are the obvious ones ... I could insert a check for null or simply handle NPE in method2. What I'm looking for is a **real world example to show when this kind of practice makes development bad/difficult.**

For example: the whole reason why I even found this, was due to Unit test being somewhat awkward ... where while testing method2 I was tempted to call method1 beforehand, rather than mock the required Class Field (which field in the real world scenario is much more complex than a simple String and hard to mock).

Comment: If I may ask the reverse, what's a real world example where your asked method would be better?

Comment: I'm not advocating for the design showed in this thread, can't think of it having benefits. I'm simply looking for possible drawbacks eg: something that shows, how development, maintenance or quality of application can be compromised due to this type of design. Your points are valid, but the obvious ones, so I keep looking for something else we might have not thought of.